# JQuery not working in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an the following element in my html:

```
<img id="teamshot" onload="load.hide()" src="img/images.jpeg" alt="image">
```

load.hide references a function in an included javascript file. The contents of this included javascript file are as follows:

```
var load = {
    hide: function()
    {
        alert("pre");
        $("#teamshot").hide();
        alert("post");
    }
}
```

I know the function is running because I get an alert box that says "pre" when the element loads, but it breaks on the jquery call. It doesn't hide the element, and it doesn't give me an alert box with the dialogue "post".

What is wrong?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded before this js?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page as well?  Do you see an error (perhaps `$ is undefined` or something to that effect?)

Comment: How do you load jQuery. I didn't realize that was necessary, and didn't notice that was necessary in any tutorial I found.

Comment: `<script src="some/path/to/jquery.js"></script>` in your `<head>`

Comment: Also if you are using jQuery keep your HTML cleaner and bind event using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @gillesc Or just use `$(...).click()`

Comment: `.click` won't replace an `onload` attribute though and in my opinion it's better to learn to use `on` which is used for all than `click` and it involves less function calls inside jQuery as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading jQuery and also the order in which you load your JavaScript files is important. You should load jQuery first, then your custom js file. For example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/file/custom.js"></script>
```